# Why I have an Invalid hook call when I call my function?

Tags: react-native, arraylist

I have 5 button "35,17,11,8,5" when I press a button I want to add the button's value to a list, so I did that.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function AddtoArray(array,value){
  console.log('a', 'a');
  const [arrayToChange, setArrayToChange] = useState(array);
  console.log('a1', 'a1');
  const [valueToAdd, setValueToAdd] = useState(value);
  console.log('a2', 'a2');
  const newArray = () => {
        setArrayToChange([...arrayToChange, value]);
    };
  console.log('b',newArray, 'b');
  return newArray;
};

function RouletteExercice1 ({ navigation }){
  const [multiplyArray, setMultiplyArray] = useState([]);

  return(
    <View>
          <Pressable onPress={() => {setMultiplyArray(AddtoArray(multiplyArray,'35'))}}>
            <Text>35</Text>
          </Pressable>
          <Pressable onPress={() => {setMultiplyArray(AddtoArray(multiplyArray,'17'))}}>
            <Text>17</Text>
          </Pressable>
          <Pressable onPress={() => {setMultiplyArray(AddtoArray(multiplyArray,'11'))}}>
            <Text>11</Text>
          </Pressable>
          <Pressable onPress={() => {setMultiplyArray(AddtoArray(multiplyArray,'8'))}}>
            <Text>8</Text>
          </Pressable>
          <Pressable onPress={() => {setMultiplyArray(AddtoArray(multiplyArray,'5'))}}>
            <Text>5</Text>
          </Pressable>
    </View>
  )

}
```

But when I press a button the app say "invalic hook call" and on the console all i have is "a a".
Can someone tell me what is the problem ? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AddtoArray function is outside of your functional component, RouletteExercice1.

When you call useState, you're adding state to the functional component that you're calling useState from. You must call useState from the functional component.

That said, you don't need state for arrayToChange or valueToAdd. You're only changing the one array, and you're passing the value to the function.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';


function RouletteExercice1 ({ navigation }){
  const [multiplyArray, setMultiplyArray] = useState([]);

  function AddtoArray(value){
    setMultiplyArray((prev) => [...prev, value])
  }

  return(
    <View>
          <Pressable onPress={() => {AddtoArray('35')}}>
            <Text>35</Text>
          </Pressable>
          <Pressable onPress={() => {AddtoArray('17')}}>
            <Text>17</Text>
          </Pressable>
          <Pressable onPress={() => {AddtoArray('11')}}>
            <Text>11</Text>
          </Pressable>
          <Pressable onPress={() => {AddtoArray('8')}}>
            <Text>8</Text>
          </Pressable>
          <Pressable onPress={() => {AddtoArray('5')}}>
            <Text>5</Text>
          </Pressable>
    </View>
  )

}
```

Comment: I 1,000% agree with this answer, just wanted to add a couple things: 1) hooks themselves are not typical JS functions, in simple components like this, they should only be at the top level of your React component and that's it. (custom hook functions are very handy but not needed in simple cases) 2) Use ESLint whenever possible to warn you of bad practices with hooks - it'll save you lots of time!